# fetch and update particular field using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, kubernetes-pod

i have a scenario,

How to fetch particular field value and also update particular field value?

**For example :**
Im deploying an application using terraform "kubernetes_deployment" resource configured with environment variables(**endpoint=abc**) and **replicas=2**.

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" “app” {
…..….
spec {
  replicas = 2
  template {
    spec {
     ….
      env {
        name  = “ENDPOINT”
        value = “abc”
    }
}
```

Once i deployed using terraform script, another script might change configurations **replicas=5** and environment values(**endpoint=xyz**)

Now i need to update only replicas to 20(if replicas < 20) through terraform script without changing the environment values(endpoint=abc)?

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" “app” {
…..….
spec {
  replicas = 20       -> only this has to reflect in apply
  template {
    spec {
     ….
      env {
        name  = “ENDPOINT”
        value = “abc”
    }
}
```

How can i fetch particular field(replicas) to compare if replicas count > 20 and update only replicas count?

Can someone with more Terraform experience help me on this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes)?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I applied ignore_changes and working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the "kubernetes_deployment" resource block, consider adding a lifecycle block. Use it to ignore changes to resource attributes that can be made outside of Terraform's knowledge.

Provide a list of resource attributes to "ignore_changes", which Terrform would ignore in subsequent runs. The arguments are the relative address of the attributes in the resource. Map and list elements can be referenced using index notation.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [spec["env"]]
  }
```

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes